# Создать очередь с приоритетом (у каждого элемента свой приоритет)

Tags: очередь, c++

Здравствуйте! Имеется задание: создать очередь с приоритетом (у каждого элемента свой приоритет). Элементы с наивысшим приоритетом ставятся в начало очереди, с наименьшим – в конец. (Последняя цифра числа является его приоритетом).
Саму функцию вставки в очередь я реализовал, но как быть с приоритетом и как он вообще реализуется?

```
void INSERT(TPQueue* &pbq,TPQueue* &peq, TElQ newEl)
{
    TPQueue* el=new TPQueue; 
    el->info=newEl;
    el->next=NULL;
    if (!isEmpty(peq)) {    
        peq->next=el;       
        peq=el;             
    } else {        
    peq=el;    
    pbq=el;     
    };
}
```

Comment: При серьезном подходе это реализуют в виде балансированоого дерева (например rb-tree) с непосредственным указанием головы.

Comment: >При серьезном подходе это реализуют в виде балансированоого дерева (например rb-tree)

думаю, фраза **А то мы по лекциям отстаем, а в методичке с лабами такого ничего нет** напрочь исключает этот самый серьезный подход)

Comment: @Юра1996, если речь о лабах, то мысль о rb-tree выбросьте. (Если интересно, можете, конечно, нагуглить MIT-шную реализацию).

Делайте по простому. Вставкой в упорядоченный (по числовому значению приоритета) двусвязный список.

Тупо перебираете элементы списка и как только приоритет следующего элемента  меньше, чем у вставляемого узла, вставляете его в список.

А вообще, для начала напишите (сами себе) ТЗ (какие функции хотите реализовать, что они делают и как с ними работать).

--

Советую выделение памяти под узлы оставить для вызывающей стороны.

Comment: @avp: в C++ rb-tree доступно из коробки как `std::map`.

@Юра1996: попробуйте `std::multimap<prio_t, value_t>` (если это вам по силам сейчас).

Comment: Вы шутите? Зачем rb-tree и multimap? Достаточно обычной [кучи][1].


  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0_(%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)

Comment: @dzhioev: Кучу надо ещё заимплементировать, `multimap` есть в стандартной библиотеке.

Comment: @VladD, видно же, что тут учебное задание. Препода вряд ли устроит решение в 3 строчки. И, справедливости ради, куча тоже есть в стандартной библиотеке, см. make_heap/push_heap/pop_heap.

Comment: @Юра1996, без описания структур данных и каких-то комментариев к ним остается только гадать.

Если `info` это приоритет (число), то зачем Вам какой-то typedef TElQ?

`pbq` это надо думать указатель на первый элемент в списке, а `pеq` это что? 

--

@VladD, как Вы собираетесь искать максимум в std::multimap?

Comment: @avp, я сделал такой вариант:

    void INSERT(TPQueue* &pbq,TPQueue* &peq, TElQ newEl)
    {   TPQueue *cur, *np;
        cur=NULL;
        np=pbq;
        TPQueue* el=new TPQueue;
    el->info=newEl;
    el->next=NULL;
    while (np!=NULL&&el->info<np->info)
    {   cur=np;
        np=np->next;    //К следующему элементу
    }   if (!isEmpty(peq)) {
        cur->next=el;
        el->prev=cur;
        if(np!=NULL){
            np->prev=el;
            el->next=np;}
    } else {
        el->next=pbq;
        if(pbq!=NULL)pbq->prev=el;
            pbq=el;
            peq=el;};
    }

Comment: @avp, описание структуры:

    typedef int TElQ;
    typedef struct SQueue{
        TElQ info;
        SQueue *next;
        SQueue *prev;
                } TPQueue;

pbq - указатель на первый элемент в списке, а peq - указатель на последний элемент

Comment: @dzhioev: Круто, не знал. Спасибо!

@avp: по идее, через [`equal_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/equal_range) должно получиться.

Comment: @Юра1996, `peq` Вы почему-то меняете только в одном месте, ну, да дело не в этом. Для начала на него можно и не обращать внимания.

А вот `next` и `prev` при вставке надо аккуратно менять у всех участников (и не забыть при вставке новой головы изменить `pbq`).

Этот код явно нерабочий.

--

@VladD, Вы же не знаете значения хранимых ключей. Что именно передавать в `equal_range`?

--

@dzhioev, Вы так пишете о куче, что можно подумать, что по сравнению с деревом там все реализуется десятком строк.

(для сравнения  какие-то коды rb_tree.c 460 строк, а fib.c (найденная по Вашей ссылке) -- 696).

Comment: @avp: угу, `rbegin`, не сообразил что-то сходу.

Comment: @avp, так fib.c это случайно не фибоначиева куча? =) У обычной кучи реализация очень простая, я скорее всего даже по памяти смогу написать. А вот у RB-Tree есть несколько типов вращения, которые запомнить почти невозможно.

Answer (score 3):

Классическая приоритетная очередь всегда на базе бинарной куче.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

template<typename T, typename Cmp>
class TPQueue {
private:
   T*      arr;
   size_t  cnt;
   size_t  mem;
   Cmp     cmp;
public:

   TPQueue(void): arr(NULL), cnt(0), mem(16){}
   ~TPQueue() {
       this->clear();
   }

   TPQueue(const TPQueue&);
   TPQueue& operator = (const TPQueue&);
public:

   bool  push(const T& val) {
       size_t  i, p;
       T tmp;

       if(! this->_alloc())
           return false;
       arr[cnt] = val;

       i = cnt;
       p = (! i) ? 0 : (i - 1) >> 1;

       while((i > 0) && ! cmp(arr[p], arr[i])) {
           tmp    = arr[i];
           arr[i] = arr[p];
           arr[p] = tmp;

           i = p--;
           if(! i)
               break;
           p >>= 1;
       }
       ++cnt;
       return true;
   }

   void  pop(void) {
       if(cnt > 1) {
           arr[0] = arr[--cnt];
           this->this_heapify(0);
       } else
           cnt = 0;
   }

   T& top(void) { return arr[0]; }
   T& top(void) const { return arr[0]; }

   bool empty(void) const { return (! cnt); }

   size_t  size(void) const { return cnt; }

   void clear(void) {
       if(arr != NULL)
           delete[] arr;
       arr = NULL;
       cnt = 0;
       mem = 16; 
   }

private:

   bool _alloc(void) {
      size_t tmem;
      T* tmp;

      if(arr == NULL) {
           arr = new T[mem];
           if(arr == NULL)
                return false;
      }

      if((cnt + 1) >= mem) {
           tmem = cnt + 1 + cnt / 3;
           tmp  = new T[tmem];
           if(tmp == NULL)
                return false;
           for(size_t i = 0u; i < cnt; ++i)
                 tmp[i] = arr[i];
           delete[] arr;
           arr = tmp;
           mem = tmem;
       }
       return true;
   }

   void  this_heapify(size_t index) {
       size_t l, r, big;
       T  tmp;

       while(1) {
           l = (index << 1) + 1u;
           r = (index << 1) + 2u;

           if((l < cnt) && cmp(arr[l], arr[index]))
                big = l;
           else
                big = index;

           if((r < cnt) && cmp(arr[r], arr[big]))
                big = r;

           if(big != index) {
                tmp = arr[index];
                arr[index] = arr[big];
                arr[big]   = tmp;
                index = big;
           } else
                break;
       }
   }
};

struct cmp {
   bool operator () (const int& a, const int& b) const{
       return (a > b);
   }
};

int main(void){
    TPQueue<int, cmp> pq;

    for(int i = 0; i < 30; ++i)
        pq.push(rand() % 400);

    while(! pq.empty()){
        printf("%d\n", pq.top());
        pq.pop();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Если уж С++, то `new` никогда не возвращает `NULL`, да и проверка на `NULL` в `delete` лишняя.

А Вы считаете, что лучше `void` а не `T&`  `.pop()` ?

Comment: через массив я уже реализовывал, но здесь именно у меня стоит задание - реализовать через линейный список! и я просто не знаю как в функции связать указатель на последний элемент списка(вернее с чем его связать)

Comment: @Юра1996, сейчас что-нибудь набросаю.

Answer (score 1):

[[[[@Юра1996](/users/17919/%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B01996)](/users/17919/%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B01996)](/users/17919/%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B01996)](/users/17919/%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B01996), у меня лимит комментариев закончился.

Действительно, можете посмотреть на [кучу](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0), как советовал [[@dzhioev](/users/552/dzhioev)](/users/552/dzhioev). Все-таки гарантированное логарифмическое от количества элементов время выполнения запросов стоит того, чтобы разобраться с этим поначалу неочевидным алгоритмом.

Я глянул, там все должно просто получаться.

Только учтите, что у Вас элементы очереди с одинаковым приоритетом должны выбираться в порядке поступления в очередь. Соответственно, ключ элемента в куче нужно делать составным. Что-то вроде

```
 struct queuekey {
    long priority;
    unsigned long seqno;
 };
```

А `seqno` в ключе это может быть просто последовательно убывающий (это чтобы у более ранних элементов числовое значение ключа с одним и тем же приоритетом было больше) номер вызова функции `insert_pqueue()`, который она же и добавит. Т.е. прототип

```
 void insert_pqueue (struct pqueue *queue, long priority, void *user_data);
```

какой-то такой.

А сама очередь может быть сделана так

```
 struct udata {
    struct queuekey;
    void *user_data;
 };
 struct pqueue {
    size_t size, capacity;
    struct udata *data;
 };
```

По сути она представляется динамическим массивом data[], который Вы будете наращивать, вызывая realloc().

Элемент с максимальным приоритетом, вставленный ранее остальных всегда будет в

```
queue->data[0];
```

Попробуйте. Если будут вопросы -- задавайте.

**UPDATE**

[[[[@Юра1996](/users/17919/%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B01996)](/users/17919/%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B01996)](/users/17919/%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B01996)](/users/17919/%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B01996), поскольку Вы просили вариант со списками, то я решил, что в такой лучше будет использовать два уровня списков.

На внешнем уровне двусвязный упорядоченный по приоритетам список, элементами которого будут списки с данными пользователя в порядке их поступления (т.е. обычные очереди).

Это позволит сократить число просматриваемых элементов при добавлении нового в очередь. Собственно, в цикле просматриваем только элементы верхнего уровня, одновременно находя место вставки в список новой очереди, если такого приоритета еще не было. Сами данные пользователя вставляются в конец найденной (или создаваемой) очереди. Поскольку поддерживаем два указателя (на первый и последний в очереди), то просмотр ее не нужен.

При выборке (удалении) наиболее приоритетного элемента очереди циклов нет вообще.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

struct uitem {
  struct uitem *next;
  void *udata;
};
struct prio {
  struct prio *next, *prev;
  long prio;
  struct uitem *head, *tail; // все элементы с данным приоритетом
};
struct prioqueue {
  struct prio *head, *tail;
  size_t size;
};

#define PQ_INIT() ((struct prioqueue){0, 0, 0})

void pq_insert(struct prioqueue *q, long prio, void *data);
long pq_peek(struct prioqueue *q, void **udata);
long pq_remove(struct prioqueue *q, void **udata);
struct prio *pq_find(struct prioqueue *q, long prio);

static struct prio *
get_priostr (long prio)
{
  struct prio *t = (typeof(t))malloc(sizeof(struct prio));
  t->next = t->prev = 0;
  t->head = t->tail = 0;
  t->prio = prio;

  return t;
}

struct prio *
pq_find (struct prioqueue *q, long prio)
{
  struct prio *t = q->head;

  while (t) {
    if (t->prio <= prio)
      break;
    t = t->next;
  }

  return t;
}

void
pq_insert (struct prioqueue *q, long prio, void *data)
{
  struct uitem *ui = (typeof(ui))malloc(sizeof(*ui));
  ui->udata = data;
  ui->next = 0;

  if (!q->head) {
    q->head = q->tail = get_priostr(prio);
    q->head->head = q->head->tail = ui;
  } else {
    struct prio *t = pq_find(q, prio); // insert before or to tail if t == 0
    if (!t || t->prio != prio) { // new priority
      struct prio *np = get_priostr(prio);
      np->head = np->tail = ui;
      if (!t) {
        q->tail->next = np;
        np->prev = q->tail;
        q->tail = np;
      } else {
        if ((np->prev = t->prev))
          np->prev->next = np;
        np->next = t;
        t->prev = np;
        if (t == q->head)
          q->head = np;
      }
    } else { // same priority, add to tail
      t->tail->next = ui;
      t->tail = ui;
    }
  }
  q->size++;
}

long
pq_peek (struct prioqueue *q, void **data)
{
  if (!q->head) {
    *data = 0;
    return LONG_MIN;
  }
  *data = q->head->head->udata;
  return q->head->prio;
}

long
pq_remove (struct prioqueue *q, void **data)
{
  if (!q->head) {
    *data = 0;
    return LONG_MIN;
  }
  struct uitem *ui = q->head->head;
  *data = ui->udata;
  long res = q->head->prio;

  if (!(q->head->head = ui->next)) {
    struct prio *p = q->head;
    if (!(q->head = p->next))
      q->tail = 0;
    else 
      q->head->prev = 0;
    free(p);
  }
  free(ui);
  q->size--;
  return res;
}

void
pr_print (struct prioqueue *q)
{
  printf ("queue size: %ld\n", q->size);
  struct prio *p = q->head;
  struct uitem *t;

  while (p) {
    printf ("priority: %ld\n", p->prio);
    for (t = p->head; t; t = t->next)
      printf("    :%s", (char *)t->udata);
    p = p->next;
  }
}

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  struct prioqueue q1 =  PQ_INIT();
  char str[1000];

  while (fgets(str, 1000, stdin)) {
    int ipr = atoi(str);
    char *r;
    long mp;

    if (str[0] == '.') {
      mp = pq_remove(&q1, (void **)&r);
      printf ("remove: %ld [%s] size: %ld\n", mp, r, q1.size);
      free(r);
    } else if (str[0] == '?')
      pr_print(&q1);
    else 
      pq_insert(&q1, ipr, strdup(str));

    mp = pq_peek(&q1, (void **)&r);
    printf ("peek: %ld [%s] size: %ld\n", mp, r, q1.size);
  }

  exit(0);
}
```

Компилировал g++ и gcc. Надеюсь, разберетесь.

Comment: @Юра1996, реализация но списках в **UPDATE** моего ответа.